# Flutter Google Sign In - This App isn't verified error

Tags: flutter, google-signin, google-authentication

I'm getting a 'This app isn't verified' error when I use the Flutter google_sign_in plug in. I want to get authorisation to Google Drive so added it to the google sign-in scope:

```
scopes: ['email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
```

And it is the request for the drive scope that is causing the error screen to come up ( I tested it with just email and works fine).
If I look at the docs it seems that Google are saying I have to verify the app, however this is a test app to see if I can get the functionality that a client has requested working with Google Drive and won't ever be promoted. 
Does anyone know how I can remove this error message for test purposes only?

Many thanks

Here's the actual screen with the error:

[image: Here's the screen shot]

Comment: You can proceed and continue the flow by clicking `advanced ` but this message wont be removed unless the app is verfied.

Comment: Thanks @SahdeepSingh please add this as an answer and I'll accept it and up vote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above warning shows when the app isn't verified. Google consents user that the app is not verifed yet and you are sharing sensitive data to it.

We can proceed and complete our flow by clicking the `Advanced` at bottom left. Once app is verfied this warning will be removed automatically.

Anyone can follow instruction listed on here

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en